# node app.js localhost not working

Tags: node.js

on WINDOWS ...after install express-seed and node.js for the "blog" tutorial, i get the same cmd prompt after typing node app.js.
    another time i got body parser and error handling errors
         i tried alot of solutions, even had a local host run with another tutorial, but i would like to run from the blog tutorial due to some slight differences of the set-up.
     Of course im a newb, and i know theres tons of answers on the forum, but none are correcting my issue...please help.
and everytime i try to post my report on here it errors me saying i have to indent each line 4 spaces. im just losing in general. 
Is there a step im missing? all the tut's say just do 'this' and 'this' and i have a local host running so i can make changes to views. any help?

```
// Module dependencies.

var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure( function() {

});

// Routes

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: indent the first line by moving four space and keep two line space between your code and your comment, that should work, or upload your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link here

Comment: Based on the information that you have provided, we cannot help you with the issue that you face. You can improve the question by adding a link to the tutorial that you mention, pasting the error that you get. As for the code, type your code and hit Ctrl + K => It will indent the code for you.

Comment: Do you want us to guess your code?

Comment: it wont let me paste script? how can i paste the code? keeps telling me to indent 4 spaces, then code gets all sloppy         http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb                  web page im trying out

Comment: // Module dependencies.
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure( function() {
});

// Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);

Answer (score 2):

what version of node & express are you running?

From the command line you can check with:

```
node --version
```

and

```
express --version
```

From your code, it looks like an older version of express (version 3 or less), but I'm betting you didn't specify the version on the npm install, which will give you the latest version (4+).  There's a lot of breaking changes between those versions, so you can't run old code with the new framework successfully.  My bet is that your blog tutorial hasn't been updated to express 4.x yet.

Comment: node=v0.12.7, express=4.13.2 and im guessing that tutorial is scrapped unless i use that specified material? anyone else have a good updated tut to create a blog?

Comment: It's certainly possible to update the code yourself to go from 3 to 4, the changes are well documented:  http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html

Comment: so install the express 4 changes? or do i already have the changes and all i do is change the code?

Comment: i think making a blog is out of question with JS? close thread please, i will just try another tut and wing it. thank you for your time

Comment: Yes, you have Express 4 installed. Use the link I sent you to update your code.

Comment: i tried, and failed, i am currently just trying it from scratch. i dont know if i am that ignorant or if windows is preventing the changes but i wound up getting so frustrated. im currently on tuts+ trying to figure something out. my whole goal was to create a blog-like template with some basic functions to start a blog-tpye journal on my perspective of the in's and outs of developing a web page. kind of like a "keep-track-for other learners". just to show the steps taken , as well as the down falls on the way to a successful creation.please contact me if you run into any more current info,